# SSRS reports with querystring

Tags: reporting-services

I am unable to access SSRS reports by passing parameter as a querystring. It doesn't yield any result. I did try passing parameter with &rs:par1=value or with &rc: as well.

SSRS reports contains spaces as well. URL which provides all report's list is like: http://ipaddress:port/Reports/Pages/Folder.aspx?ItemPath=%2fMyfolder

After clicking on any report http://ipaddress:port/Reports/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=%2fMyfolder%2fReused+Report+v2

I did look at .rdl file & tried suffixing parameter like &rs:par1=value or &rc:par1=value but didn't work.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use reportServer URL ( http://ipaddress:port/Reportserver) instead of Report Manager URL ( http://ipaddress:port/Repors) and frame URL like

**http://hostname:portnumber/ReportServer?/AdventureWorks 2008R2/Employee_Sales_Summary_2008R2&ReportMonth=3&ReportYear=2008**

Comment: got that. will report work/show along with parameters if user need to click on "view report" button?

Comment: Yep.  We use 'ReportServer' for all of our frontend and client facing reports.  It's fully functional.

Comment: I tried passing parameter to ipaddress:port/Reports/Report&para1=val but it didn't work. I didn't see value shown in textbox available in report. Am I missing something?

Comment: `http://ipaddress:port/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fMyFolder%2fReused+Report+v2`

Also, try using https.  We block http connections on ours.

Comment: doesn't accept https.  I didn't see value shown in textbox available in report. What's wrong? Got any inputs?

Answer (score 0):

.cshtml

```
<iframe id="frmReport" src="ReportURL" frameborder="0"  scrolling="no">
```

controller(GET method)

```
 ReportURL = String.Format("../../Report/WebForm.aspx?Param1Name={0}&Param2Name={1}",Param1Value, Param2Value);
```

WebForm.aspx.cs page

Include---> (`using ReportParameter = Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportParameter;`)

```
    ReportParameter[] param = new ReportParameter[2];

param[0] = new ReportParameter("Param1Name", Request["Param1Name"].ToString());
```

param[1] = new ReportParameter("Param2Name", Request["Param2Name"].ToString());

```
 ReportViewer1.ServerReport.SetParameters(param);
```