# Calling SSRS report from a Winforms Application

Tags: vb.net, winforms, reporting-services, reportviewer

I have created a Winforms app that is used to call a SSRS report. When it comes to accessing the report I was able to get the report to come up but I have to type in the DataSource credentials to get the report to open and then I have to enter in all the parameters. Is there a way to just have the DataSource credentials get passed in as well as the parameters. The reason for this is so that employees can access a report without having to know the DataSource credentials.

Note: For the parameters I have created list boxes and text entry fields to take in the values for the parameters. Is there a way to pass the values into the report as well so the user doesn't have to type them in when the report loads up?

I am learning all of this on the fly so any input will be very much appreciated.

I've tried to look up examples on google but everything is based on the webforms and not on winforms I'm not sure if they are equally the same though when it comes to configuration.

Comment: Is this Native reports, or SharePoint deployed, and are you querying the SSRS service direct?

Comment: For the URL issue, see this discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/q/29001290/1690217

Comment: so this is the set up. I created the report with a stored procedure in sql then built the report in ssrs and deployed it to our report server. I'm not really familiar with the terminology. I do know that I added the report server path and the path to the report though. If that is helpful.

Comment: Please let us know how the report is "loaded up". Are you using a ReportViewer control in your application or do you just follow a hyperlink (so the report is opened in a new browser window/tab)? Do the users have access to the report but not to the datasource? Do you want to configure specific (fix) credentials for the datasource?

Comment: The report is loaded through the ReportViewer control and its a server report. the users will only have access to the report and not the datasource. i would just like to pass the datasource credentials in code so that they don't have to type in the password,

Comment: What is your security model on the Stored Procedure that the report uses? Are you using Active Directory authentication?